# Unable to load DLL 'linphone'

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-4.8, linphone, linphone-sdk

I'm trying to create a simple Voip client application using the Linphone NuGet (LinphoneSDK.5.1.73.nupkg).

For that I created a solution with two C# projects (target framework: **.net Framework 4.8**, ; target platform: **x86**):
one as a wrapper of Linphone (named as **My.Voip**) and the other for the application itself (named as **My.Voip.Client**).

In My.Voip, I added the Nuget **LinphoneSDK 5.1.73**, that I previously downloaded to my computer.

In this project, I created a class with a function that returns the version of Linphone, following the tutorial from Linphone.

```
using Linphone;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace My.Voip
{
    public class Engine
    {
        public Core StoredCore { get; set; }

        public string Version()
        {

            Factory factory = Factory.Instance;
            string assetsPath = Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "share");
            factory.TopResourcesDir = assetsPath;
            factory.DataResourcesDir = assetsPath;
            factory.SoundResourcesDir = Path.Combine(assetsPath, "sounds", "linphone");
            factory.RingResourcesDir = Path.Combine(factory.SoundResourcesDir, "rings");
            factory.ImageResourcesDir = Path.Combine(assetsPath, "images");
            factory.MspluginsDir = ".";

            Core core = factory.CreateCore("", "", IntPtr.Zero);


            // You should store the Core to keep a reference to it at all times while your app is alive.
            // A good solution for that is to either subclass the Application object or create a Service.
            StoredCore = core;
            return Core.Version;
        }
    }
}
```

In My.Voip.Client, I added a reference to the My.Voip project.

Now, in My.Voip.Client, I created a winform that, on load shows the version of Linphone.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            My.Voip.Engine x = new My.Voip.Engine();
            MessageBox.Show(x.Version());
            
        }
```

The problem that I'm facing is that i get an error when I invoke the Version method:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'linphone': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

The error is traced back to the file ~My.Voip\linphonecs\LinphoneWrapper.cs, line 33104:

```
        static public Linphone.Factory Instance
        {
            get
            {
                IntPtr ptr = linphone_factory_get(); //<-Exception is thrown here
                Linphone.Factory obj = fromNativePtr<Linphone.Factory>(ptr, true);
                return obj;
            }
        }
```

The Instance is invoked in the class Engine->function Version->**Factory factory = Factory.Instance;**

I've tried to change the target platform as x64 and AnyCPU, reference the Nuget directly to the winforms application, but I get always the same error. I've, also, tried to use the Nuget directly from the Linphone repository, and the result is the same error, too.

What do I need to do to run this correctly?

Comment: I think your dll is not loaded in runtime. Can you try Assembly.LoadFrom("your.dll"); to verify it.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [LinPhone Wiki](https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/Windows%20UWP/#HFromourPackageRegistry283E3Dv5.2.029) and [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I've already followed the LinPhone Wiki instructions and the result is the same

Comment: You may consider using a newer version of the package (>= v5.2.0) that uses NuGet package manager.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I've already done that. I've tried using the LinphoneSDK.Windows 5.2.78 and the result is the same error, too.

Comment: That library has a bunch of unmanaged DLL dependencies, linphone is just one of them.  Because they are unmanaged, the build system doesn't know that these dlls have to be copied into the My.Voip.Client project's build directory.  You have to help, use xcopy in a post-build event.

Answer (score -1):

The following describes the necessary steps to use NuGet package [LinphoneSDK.Windows](https://wiki.linphone.org/xwiki/wiki/public/view/Lib/Getting%20started/Windows%20UWP/#HFromourPackageRegistry283E3Dv5.2.029) (v5.2.77) in a WinForms project.

Since only x86 files exist for WinForms, before adding the NuGet package one needs to switch the build configuration from `AnyCPU` to `x86`.

At the end of this post (under *Additional Information*), you'll find the troubleshooting process I used to make the determination that the project needs to target *x86*.

---

Try the following:

**Create a new Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)** (name: VoipTest; Framework: .NET Framework 4.8)

[image]

**Use Configuration Manager to change the configuration to x86**

- In VS menu, click **Build**
- Select **Configuration Manager...**
- Select the drop-down under **Active solution platform**, select `<New...>`
  [image]
- Select the drop-down under **Type or select the new platform**, select `X86`

  [image]
- Click **OK**

  [image]
- Click **Close**

**Add NuGet package source**

- In VS menu, click **Tools**
- Select **Options...**
- Expand **NuGet Package Manager**
- Select **General**
- Under **Package Management**, select **PackageReference**
- Select **Package Sources**

  [image]
- Click [image]
- You'll now see:

  [image]
- For name, enter **Linphone** (if desired the name can be changed)
- For Source, enter:  `https://gitlab.linphone.org/api/v4/projects/411/packages/nuget/index.json`
- Click **Update**

  [image]
- Click **OK**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

**Add NuGet package** (name: )

- In Solution Explorer, right-click <project name> (ex: VoipTest)
- Select **Manage NuGet Packages...**
- Change the **Package source** to **Linphone**

  [image]
- Select **LinphoneSDK.Windows**

  [image]
- Select version **5.2.77**

  [image]
- Click **Install**
- If a message box appears, click **OK**

**Create a new class** (name: Engine**)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Linphone;

namespace VoipTest
{
    public class Engine : IDisposable
    {
        private Core _core = null;

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_core != null)
            {
                _core.Stop();
            }
        }

        public string Version()
        {
            string configFolder = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "LinPhoneConfig");
            Debug.WriteLine($"configFolder: {configFolder}");

            Factory factory = Factory.Instance;
            _core = factory.CreateCore(configFolder, null, IntPtr.Zero);

            //Linphone.Factory.Instance.CreateCore(configFolder, null, IntPtr.Zero);

            _core.Start();

            Debug.WriteLine($"version: {Core.Version}");

            return Core.Version;
        }
    }
}
```

**Add Button to Form1** (name: btnRun)

**Double-click the button to add *Click* event handler**

**Form1.cs**

```
private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Engine engine = new Engine())
    {
        string version = engine.Version();

        Debug.WriteLine($"version: {version}");
    }
}
```

When you build the solution, you'll notice that the DLLs get copied to the output directory.

---

**Additional Information**:

NuGet packages are downloaded to `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages` which is where you'll find `linphonesdk.windows\5.2.77`. When one builds the project, the appropriate `.targets` file (under `linphonesdk.windows\5.2.77\build\<version>`) is read. If one opens `LinphoneSDK.Windows.targets` file using Notepad, one sees the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LinphoneSDK-Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'Win32'">x86</LinphoneSDK-Platform>
    <LinphoneSDK-Platform Condition="'$(Platform)' != 'Win32'">$(Platform)</LinphoneSDK-Platform>
    <LinphoneSDK-Framework Condition="'$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)' != 'UAP10.0' and '$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)' != 'UAP'">netcore</LinphoneSDK-Framework>
    <LinphoneSDK-Framework Condition="'$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)' == 'UAP10.0' or '$(TargetPlatformIdentifier)' == 'UAP'">uap10.0</LinphoneSDK-Framework>
    <LinphoneSDK-Content Condition="'$(LinphoneSDK-Content)' == ''">share</LinphoneSDK-Content>
    <LinphoneSDK-LibrariesPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\..\lib\$(LinphoneSDK-Framework)\$(LinphoneSDK-Platform)</LinphoneSDK-LibrariesPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more information see [MSBuild .targets files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-dot-targets-files?view=vs-2022).

In order to figure out what values are being used, in Visual Studio, one can

**Change the *verbosity* of the build process**

- In VS menu, click **Tools**
- Select **Options**
- Expand **Projects and Solutions**
- Select **Build and Run**
- Under **MSBuild project build output verbosity**, change to **Diagnostic**
- Click **OK**

Then clean and re-build the project.

In order to know the values that are being used, in the Output window, search for `Platform`. When configuration has been set to *x86* one sees `Platform = x86`.

Next search for `TargetPlatformIdentifier`. For a WinForms app, one sees `TargetPlatformIdentifier = Windows`.

Now search for `LinphoneSDK-Framework`, and `LinphoneSDK-LibrariesPath`, and `LinphoneSDK-Platform`. When configuration is set to *x86*, One sees:

```
1>LinphoneSDK-Content = share
1>LinphoneSDK-Framework = netcore
1>LinphoneSDK-LibrariesPath = C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\linphonesdk.windows\5.2.77\build\net48\\..\..\lib\netcore\x86
1>LinphoneSDK-Platform = x86
```

And if the build configuration is set to *x64*:

```
1>LinphoneSDK-Content = share
1>LinphoneSDK-Framework = netcore
1>LinphoneSDK-LibrariesPath = C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\linphonesdk.windows\5.2.77\build\net48\\..\..\lib\netcore\x64
1>LinphoneSDK-Platform = x64
```

The path

```
C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\linphonesdk.windows\5.2.77\build\net48\\..\..\lib\netcore\x64
```

is the same as

```
C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\linphonesdk.windows\5.2.77\lib\netcore\x64
```

If one opens Windows Explorer and goes to the path, one notices that this path doesn't exist.

Likewise for *AnyCPU*:

```
1>LinphoneSDK-Content = share
1>LinphoneSDK-Framework = netcore
1>LinphoneSDK-LibrariesPath = C:\Users\<username>\.nuget\packages\linphonesdk.windows\5.2.77\build\net48\\..\..\lib\netcore\AnyCPU
1>LinphoneSDK-Platform = AnyCPU
```

Since the package only contains DLL files for *x86* for the type of project that we've created, one needs to compile for *x86* or no DLLs will be copied to the output folder.